# ArcGIS 10.2 Windows 7 only uses 4Gb of RAM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, windows-7, 64bit

I have 16Gb and have installed 64-bit background processing, but ArcMap seems to only be able to access 4Gb. I can use more in total with other programs. Is there a setting somewhere in Windows or ArcGIS that is only allowing it to access 4GB? Thanks.

Comment: This is really amazing.

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38343).

ArcMap (ArcMap.exe) is still a 32bit application and as such is limited to 4GB. The 64 bit background processing addon allows [some](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Background_Geoprocessing_64_bit/002100000040000000/) geoprocessing tools (RuntimeLocalServer.exe) to run in 64bit.